# jQuery prevent input default action

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I have an ajax form I would like to prevent from preforming an action when submitted and have tried numerous methods and nothing works. My first method was:

```
 return false;
```

and then I tried

```
event.preventDefault();
```

event being the callback name or whatever you call it.

```
function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

Heres the HTML I am using right now:

```
<form class="main_search" method="POST" action="ajaxsearch.php">
    <input type="text" class="editable" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

Heres the test javascript I set up:

```
$('.main_search').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(console.log(event)); //Log the event if captured
});
```

Neither method works but the weird part is that they work on different things like buttons but they don't work on this one form. Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: This is weird: `event.preventDefault(console.log(event));` Those should be two lines (`event.preventDefault();` doesn't take any arguments).

Comment: @JaredFarrish That would be a good reason but it still doesn't work

Comment: I didn't say it was *a reason*, I said *this is weird*. Otherwise, I would have posted it as *an answer*. `;)`

Comment: What's you've posted seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/5TVGn/ Is this a dynamically added form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with your specific problem (ie, *inserting dynamically generated form*), use [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). You're better off not using `document.body` as the parent observer (as `$.live()` essentially does) with `$.on()`, so the following would be appropriate (considering your actual markup):

```
<div id="searches">
    <form class="main_search" method="POST" action="ajaxsearch.php">
        <input type="text" class="editable" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
</div>

var $main_search = $('.main_search'),
    $searches = $('#searches');

$searches.on('submit', '.main_search', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event); //Log the event if captured
});

setInterval(function(){
    $searches.append($main_search.clone());
}, 5000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5TVGn/2/

Answer (score 1):

I set up a JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XM679/

Could it be you forgot to wrap it into `$(document).ready(function() {}` ?
If this didn't solve the problem: Since the fiddle is working - we would need your context to help more.